# jQuery datepicker to count days from today

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have this code, it counts days between two dates with jqueryUI datepicker.

How can I get rid of the first input entirely and just count days from today?

```js
function showDays() {
    var start = $('#arr_date').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#dep_date').datepicker('getDate');
    if (!start || !end) return;
    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    $('#num_nights').val(days);
}

$("#arr_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: showDays
});
$("#dep_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: showDays
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="arr_date">
<input type="text" id="dep_date">
<input type="text" id="num_nights" disabled>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `new Date()` and set its hours, minutes, seconds to `0` to match with the datepicker format. Also, use `Math.round()` on the difference.

Then you can calculate as below:

```js
function showDays() {
    var start = new Date()
    start.setHours(0);
    start.setMinutes(0);
    start.setSeconds(0);
    
    var end = $('#dep_date').datepicker('getDate');
    if (!start || !end) return;
    var days = Math.round((end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
    $('#num_nights').val(days);
}

$("#dep_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: showDays
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="dep_date">
<input type="text" id="num_nights" disabled>
```